# ¿Como actualizar contenido en aplicación android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una galería en android con las librerias "Volley" y "Glide" que obtiene imágenes de un .json el problema es que si agrego una nueva imagen el usuario tiene que cerrar completamente la app para que se vuelvan a descargar los datos y eso no es bueno, como se resolvería este problema? pensaba en un "Swipe Down" pero espero encontrar otras soluciones, espero su consejo, gracias!.

Comment: como agregas la nueva imagen? un boton, tomas una foto?? y como consumes el .json?

Comment: La imagen la agrego modificando el archivo json que esta en un servidor

Comment: Entonces mientras el usuario tenga abierta la aplicación nunca va a poder volver a actualizar esa lista por si sola. Tienes dos opciones crear un boton "actualizar" que lea ese json nuevamente o bien hacer una tarea asincrona que cada cierto tiempo este consultado a ese json y actualizando tu lista de imagenes. O como tu dices un Swipe Down

Comment: Aún soy novato pero se me ocurre que podrías hacer la carga de datos en el onCreate de la actividad y reiniciarla cada ves que quieras que se vuelvan a cargar.

Answer (score 3):

La opción más común es usar un **[SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html#AddSwipeWidget)** en el cual implementarias la recarga de nuevos datos y la actualización de estos datos en el [Adapter](https://youtu.be/Pvt_japKYLY).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí hay un excelente tutorial de nuestros amigos de ["Hermosa Programación"](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/03/android-swiperefreshlayout-recyclerview/).